# Why is my Checkbox (Material-UI) not updating? I am using useState, useEffect, alongside with Checkbox from Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Why is my checkbox (Material-UI) not updating? I am using useState, useEffect, alongside with Checkbox from Material-UI. This is especially weird because the `{isLiked ? <p>liked</p> : <p>not liked</p>}` updates properly without any problem but it's just the Checkbox that is not working. I am trying to update the checked status of the Checkbox using the defaultChecked attribute. It worked when I set the isLiked Boolean directly, but once I tried to use useState and useEffect, it just stopped working. Here is my code:

```
const Post = ({ createdOn, text, username, comments, likedUsers }) => {
    const d = new Date(createdOn);
    const userDetails = useAuthState();

    const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = React.useState(false);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (userDetails.user){
            if (likedUsers.indexOf(userDetails.user.user_id) !== -1)
                setIsLiked(true)              
        }
    },[])
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h3>{text}</h3>
               
                <div>
                    <span>{d.toLocaleDateString()}</span>&nbsp;<span>{d.toLocaleTimeString()}</span>
                </div>
                <div>{username}</div>
                <div>
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                            <Checkbox
                                icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
                                checkedIcon={<Favorite />}
                                name="checkedH"
                                defaultChecked={isLiked}
                                
                            />}
                    />{likedUsers.length}
                </div>
                <Commentlist comments={comments} />
                {isLiked ? <p>liked</p> : <p>not liked</p>}
                
                <hr />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Post
```

Thanks in advance.

Here is a similar code snippet that reproduces the problem without the external dependencies:

```
import React from "react";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import Favorite from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import FavoriteBorder from "@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder";

const Post = () => {
  const likedUsers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  const username = "user1";
  const user = {
    user_id: 1,
    username
  };
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      if (likedUsers.indexOf(user.user_id) !== -1) setIsLiked(true);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div>{user.username}</div>
        <div>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox
                icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
                checkedIcon={<Favorite />}
                name="checkedH"
                defaultChecked={isLiked}
              />
            }
          />
          {likedUsers.length}
        </div>
        {isLiked ? <p>liked</p> : <p>not liked</p>}

        <hr />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

When the page first loads I would compare the current user id to see whether it is in the "likedUsers" array in each post to determine whether the user has liked the post or not, and heart Checkbox would show this initial state. Every time the user clicks the heart, it would send a put request to the backend to toggle the status in the database.
The "likedUsers" array is a property of each post being fetched when the page is being loaded and is passed down to the Post component. I still haven't coded the put request part yet though, so it is not shown in the question.

Comment: Could you provide an example code that can repro your issue? Checkbox is not updating is probably related to your useEffect dependencies. You can try adding the necessary ones.

Comment: Is there any reason you're doing this with useEffect? Why not just add an event handler on that checkbox and let it toggles the state? Something like this, and you can just set the default value by the state: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-cookies-x82ji?file=/src/App.js

Comment: When I tried doing it without useEffect, just using useState alone, I got a "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.” error. But I am using useState because I think have to keep track of the value of isLiked and send a put request to the backend when the use toggles the state afterwards when the user checks and unchecks the heart checkbox

Comment: Did you check the codesanbox link? Is that what you want to achive?

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't ask clearly. When the page first loads I would compare the current user id to see whether it is in the "likedUsers" array in each post to determine whether the user has liked the post or not, and heart Checkbox would show this initial state. Every time the user clicks the heart, it would send a put request to the backend to toggle the status in the database.

Comment: The "likedUsers" array is a property of each post being fetched when the page is being loaded and is passed down to the Post component. I still haven't coded the put request part yet though, so it is not shown in the question. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't understand why you want the useEffect but you can try this:

`Checkbox` needs `checked` property to being active. And an event handler `onChange` to do this.

```
const handleCheckbox = () => {
    setIsLiked(!isLiked);
  };

<FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox
                icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
                checkedIcon={<Favorite />}
                name="checkedH"
                checked={isLiked}
                onChange={handleCheckbox}
              />
            }
          />
```

Please check the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-curran-boj0s)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to see if I could make the page show the initial state that was pulled from the backend (passed down as an array called likedUsers in each post). It checks whether the user is one of those who liked the post.

Comment: Yes I saw this later at comments above, besides I did not remove your `useEffect`, please check the link example.

Comment: It still didn't work. I think the "defaultChecked" attribute might need to be used but I'm not sure.

Comment: I believe that we have misunderstand what you need. But in the example the checkbox is checked at the beginning. What exactly do you need ?

Comment: It worked! I think I should have used the ```checked``` attribute instead of ```defaultChecked``` Thanks!